# Email is not sent to user's email address in *.js

Tags: react-native

I am going to send 5 digits to user's email address. But it is not being sent.
Here is codebase below.

```
const mailOptions = {
  from: 'example@gmail.com',
  to: email,  
  subject: 'Password Reset Token',
  text: `Your password reset token is: ${token}`
};

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: 'Error sending email' });
  } else {
    console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
    res.json({ message: 'Token sent to email!' });
  }
});
```

Please let me know what I should fix.

I couldn't see any emails were sent. Please let me know the issues. Thanks.

Comment: is this nodemailer?

Comment: There are no user’s email addresses in *.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use google app password to send an email by using the gmail.

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en

I think you used normal password for the your mailer.

Answer (score 1):

Please Verify Email Service Connection.

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
    user: 'example@gmail.com',
    pass: 'YOUR_PASSWORD'
  }
});
```

There will be several reasons but please try to test connection first and then please consider these features: Less Secure Apps & Gmail, Check the Email Parameter, Spam Filter, Network Issues, Sender Email Verification, Server Response Codes.
Hope you will sove this problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to checking up your email server setting first.
   If you are using 'Google cloud platform' for sending something to gmail users, you need to register API key & OAuth first. please double-check it's working perfectly.
2. Let me share the sample code of Nodemailer:

   ```
    let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      service: 'gmail',
      auth: {
        type: 'OAuth2',
        user: process.env.MAIL_USERNAME,
        pass: process.env.MAIL_PASSWORD,
        clientId: process.env.OAUTH_CLIENTID,
        clientSecret: process.env.OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET,
        refreshToken: process.env.OAUTH_REFRESH_TOKEN
      }
    });

    let mailOptions = {
          from: tomerpacific@gmail.com,
          to: tomerpacific@gmail.com,
          subject: 'Nodemailer Project',
          text: 'Hi from your nodemailer project'
        };

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(err, data) {
          if (err) {
            console.log("Error " + err);
          } else {
            console.log("Email sent successfully");
          }
        });
   ```